# Set up user permissions for GIT on local machine

Tags: linux, git, permissions, local

I would like to set up several remote git-repositories on a local server (linux). 
Additionally I want to set up specific permissions for each developer (everyone should only have write/read access for projects he's working on).

I am not allowed to change the group-permissions - how can I realize the permissions without changing the group-permissions?

Every solution I can find seems to be intended for ssh.

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify: You mean each developer should have only read (not write) on everyone else's stuff OR no read on everyone else's stuff?

Comment: **1)** Every developer should only have read and write access on their own repositories.

**2)** I want some repositories where multiple chosen developers have read and write access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities to host public repos.
For example you could use [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) which requires ssh or you can set up git via https on a webserver and use the servers auth systems. You can find a lot of tutorials on the internet related to that topic.

But in any case, you have to use a transport protocol (ssh/https). So you will have to use a ssh-server or web-server.

If you can't/don't want to do that, I suggest, to try [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/). You can handle permissions very easy and you are provided with a bug-tracker and a wiki for each repo.

I tried the web-server thing once and it did not work so well. For my own "small" repos, I use gitolite and for bigger projects with multiple contributors, I use bitbucket.

What you definitely won't find is a all-in-one "git-server".

Comment: the goal is to use our own hardware, so the code isn't in some cloud.

unfortunately we don't have a webserver set up. Is it possible to trick the ssh-protocol into accessing local drives?

Comment: I did some very dirty hacking once. You can add new users to the system with a primary group of your choice. If this user pushes stuff to the repo via ssh, files are created with his permissions. You can use the post-receive hook to correct this. Group-perms have to be rw on files and rwx on directories. And you must have a specific group per repo. So if a person has to have access to different repos with different groups, you need to create a new account for every repo. The inconvenience here can be diminished by using ssh-keys. This should be the last option, as it contains some bad hacks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and started working with gitolite... This took me a lot of time and I ended up using Gitlab. It does not solve your question literally, but might allow you to do exactly what you want in a clean manner.

- open-source software to manage (remote) git repositories
- manage permissions per user and per project

I installed it using the [bitnami installer](https://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab) and this got me everything up and running in less than an hour.

Comment: I don't understand how gitlab should be able to set up permissions. It looks like any other git gui - so it should use standard-git protocols to set up the permissions?

Comment: in fact gitlab hosts a set of "bare repositories" and you can define the users that are allowed to clone, read, write etc. Each developer (having acess) should clone the repository locally and push his changes...

Comment: @deltavisions if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it.